# Creating a button with macro on a different workbook

Tags: vba, excel, button

I currently have a macro which creates another workbook and adds a button to it. I've assigned a macro to the button, but I believe I still need the master workbook to actually run the macro.

Is there a way to have the macro run on the new workbook without referring to the master workbook? In other words, is it possible to programmatically add a button to a new workbook with a macro and have it be independent of the original workbook?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go like this:

- have your "master" workbook with a template worksheet whit both an ActiveX button and its corresponding code in its code pane

  say its name is "TemplateSheetWithButtonAndCode"
- in your macro use

  ```
  Worksheets("TemplateSheetWithButtonAndCode").Copy 
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "c:\MyFolder\MyWorkbooK"
  ```

this will generate a new workbook with a copy of your "template" worksheet as its only worksheet, along with necessary code to have the button work

Comment: So the worksheet code successfully copies over, but every time I click the button, it keeps referring to the the "master" macro. I've tried specifying the macro the sheet macro (i.e. sheet1.macro) but it keeps pointing to the directory of the "master file" macro. Any way to force it to refer to the sheet macro?

Comment: So it's not an `ActiveX` button but a `Form` one. In this case just redifine its `OnAction` property as per [This link](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/correcting-shape-assigned-macro-links-after-copying-worksheet-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Place the button on a template worksheet.  Place the button's associated macro in that worksheet's code area.

If you export the worksheet to another workbook, you will also be exporting the button and the macro.

Comment: which is quite what I answered... As the elder said "repetita juvant"